# reuse sql param when not using named parameters

Tags: java, sql, spring, jdbctemplate, named-parameters

I have a query that gets called with JdbcTemplate but only one param is getting sent and I need to use that one param in two where conditions.

### The Query

```
String sql = "select * from employee where salary > ? and netpay > ?";
```

### The Call

The param here is only one. I.E. if the id is `TEST123` the query needs to be

`select * from employee where id = TEST123 and name = TEST123` even though one param is getting passed.

```
getJdbcTemplate().query(sql, new Object[]{"TEST123"}, CustomResultSetExtractor());
```

Is there any way to do this from the query side instead of passing two params?

### NOTE

*I do not have access to change the way the query is called, hence I cannot add named params, or just pass an additional parameter.*

Comment: @YCF_L thanks for your effort. The problem is I don't have access to the service its self I only pass the query and they build and call. That's why I was looking for a workaround from the SQL side.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [NamedParameterJdbcTemplate](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jdbc/core/namedparam/NamedParameterJdbcTemplate.html), a JdbcTemplate wrapper:

> Template class with a basic set of JDBC operations, allowing the use of named parameters rather than traditional '?' placeholders.
>
> This class delegates to a wrapped JdbcTemplate once the substitution from named parameters to JDBC style '?' placeholders is done at execution time.

Your SQL will be with 1 parameter:

```
select * from employee where id = (:id) and name = (:id)
```

And code will be :

```
MapSqlParameterSource args = new MapSqlParameterSource();
args.addValue("id", TEST123);
return new NamedParameterJdbcTemplate(getJdbcTemplate()).query(sql , args, youRowMapper);
```

If you can't change it, you can change your query to:

```
 select * from employee where id = ? and id = name
```

Comment: I upvoted because this would be the ideal solution. But I am using a service that I pass my query and they are not using named parameters(its a service I dont have control over, I just get to pass a query), they are using these question marks. I was wondering if there was anything I could do in my query to reuse. Like `3?` where I specify the third argument.

Comment: @EduardoDennis can you send to service full SQL without parameters?

Comment: I pass the string `"select * from employee where id = ?"` and it will substitute with specific id and execute and return results. But now I needed to add the additional where. to reference that one param they are adding.

Comment: @EduardoDennis update my answer with another solution

Comment: `where id=? and id= name` what is name?

Comment: @EduardoDennis you wanted to check same value in both colums,so you can check colums values are equals

Answer (score 1):

I am amazed that you didn't find:

```
String sql = "select * from employee where id = ? and name = id";
```

Or did you mean `or` instead of `and`?

```
String sql = "select * from employee where ? in (id, name)";
```

Comment: I gave a basic example to try and see if there was a way of reusing the one param. But my actual query is select * from employee where id =? and name > ?. Is there some sql magic for that?

Comment: `name > id`? Or `name LIKE (id || '%')`? But I guess it is even more tricky.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest something else, you can repeat your param in Object array for example if your query have two `?` then generate the parameters like so :

```
String param = "TEST123";
Object[] params = IntStream.range(0, 2)
        .mapToObj(i -> param)
        .toArray();
```

This will generate an array which hold two time `TEST123` :

```
[TEST123, TEST123]
```

Then Just send the Object array to your code like you do.

```
getJdbcTemplate().query(sql, params, CustomResultSetExtractor());
```

---

If you don't know the number of hold or parameters in your query you can count them like so :

```
int numberOfHold = sql.length() - sql.replaceAll("\\?", "").length();
```